# ubuntu server - can not ping

Tags: networking, server, vmware

I have a problem to ping some network from my VMware Virutal Machine. I'm using ubuntu server 14.10, and VM network conection is set to NAT. For some reason I can not ping to www.google.com nor my host machine. I also want to be able to ping from host machine to guest.

Here are some detailed information:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all this is a DNS error. Can you paste your `/etc/resolvconf` file? Does anything else work for you from this virtual machine?

Comment: isn't /etc/resolvconf directory, which file exactly you want to see? and what do you mean exactly by anything else to work ? - I have just startup this virtual machine, and I have done changes only to /etc/network/interfaces file, that is all.

Comment: Sorry we need `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: ok, ill post in a minute

Comment: original post updated, file seems to be empty

Comment: can any1 tell me what im doing wrong and how to fix this ?

Comment: You have no DNS specified in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file.  That is for example: 
`nameserver 192.168.1.1`
in this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMWare is running on your host and you set the network to NAT? And you want to be able to ping your host as well as connect to the internet through your machines connection? I'm wondering about your static network configuration, I would have expected VMWare creating a DHCP server for you. Maybe setting the network to DHCP works better (/etc/network/interfaces):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

But if you want the server to be able to serve something in your LAN, I would recommend to change the network in VMWare to bridged. Than it will behave as if its another computer in your LAN. It could get its IP settings from your routers DHCP or you set it statically like above to settings fitting your LAN. To have DNS settings as well, you might want to add "dns-nameservers 12.34.56.78" (with your DNS servers IP (probably your router)) to /etc/network/interfaces.

More information about Ubuntu/Debian network configuration can be found here: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration