# Internet is getting disconnected frequently for Ubuntu VM

Tags: networking, 18.04, virtualbox

After Reading so many articles and posts , I am still not able to solve the problem of internet dis-connectivity inside my Ubuntu VM . I am using following tools :

```
1: Windows 10 host machine
2: Oracle VM 6.0
3: ubuntu 18.04
```

Some other info which you may require as it has been asked in other articles/posts too

```
1: Virtual-Box itself has NAT, see screen-shot [NAT-config][1]. Is it not that intelligent yet to pick correct config ? your answers will decide that.
2: output of /etc/network/config : i am not into networking so not sure what it is , tried to convert 
the settings from default this :
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

to this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

based on suggestion from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665387/ubuntu-server-can-not-ping) , but i am here searching for answers.
went through [this](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/) whole article but no clue about how can i resolve the breaking internet inside
Ubuntu VM . Is it going into sleep mode ? because when i go to Wired Connected drop down and toggle between turn-off and turn-on ,  internet comes back .
If that is not enough i even tried sharing the wifi internet see pic [Internet-Shared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc0DH.png) . But nothing seems to work out . TIA a lot.

Comment: Hmmm. My Ubuntu 18.04 server in a VM has rock solid network connectivity. Mine is a stock install with absolutely no customization (it's a testing machine). Is there any information you can provide that would help us to reproduce the problem that you are encountering? If not, then we are merely guessing in the dark.

Comment: Please let me know what info is required from my side .

Comment: Here are some logs which i am getting in syslog:Withdrawing address record for fp80::6z65:2xae:39db:4bi3 on enp0s3 Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s3.IPv6 with address fp80::6z65:2xae:39db:4bi3 on enp0s3 Interface enp0s3.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.